# Proving that $4000(1 - 0.95^n) $ is true for this situation

Tags: proof-writing

I can see why the following formula is correct, but I'm not sure how to set about proving it.

A man needs to spread 4000kg of sand over his garden. He decides to spread 200kg every day, but after the first day  he discovers that he can only spread 95% of the amount he spread the previous day.

Show that after $n$ days, he has spread $4000(1 - 0.95^n)$.

Comment: The amount of sand he spread each day is a geometric sequence.

Comment: It is an easy induction to show that each day he has $95\%$ of his previous day's sand left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(u_n)_{n\geq 1}$ the amount of sand (in kg) he spread the nth day. Now, "he decides to spread 200kg everyday" gives $u_n = 200$ for $n\geq 1$.
But "after the first day discovers that he can only spread 95% of the amount he spread the previous day", so actually $u_n = 0.95 u_{n-1}$ for $n \geq 2$.
This shows that the sequence $(u_n)$ is geometric with common ratio $r=0.95$, thus 
$$
  u_n = u_1 r^{n-1} = 200\times 0.95^{n-1}.
$$
After $n$ days, the amount of sand he has spread is
$$
\begin{align*}
  u_1 + u_2 + \dots + u_n 
    &= 200\times (1 + 0.95 + \dots + 0.95^{n-1}) \\
    &= 200\times \frac{1-0.95^n}{1-0.95} \\  
    &= 4000(1-0.95^n).
\end{align*}
$$